# ImportError: cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2' (tried all solutions on the web)

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm using the tensorflow object_detection api on Windows 10, 64-bit, with Python 3.6, 64-bit. I have protobuf and all other necessary packages installed, and protoc and all other `/model/research files` in my path. I have `string_int_label_map_pb2.py` in my `object_detection/protos` folder, but I keep getting the `ImportError: cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2'`error. Interestingly, when I open up a new Python window, I still cannot import any of the protos files using the command `from object_detection.protos import (random file in protos here)`. I've tried all the solutions I can find on the Web.

Error code:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main.py", line 26, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib
  File "C:\Users\f3d0m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib.py", line 27, in <module>
    from object_detection import eval_util
  File "C:\Users\f3d0m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection\eval_util.py", line 27, in <module>
    from object_detection.metrics import coco_evaluation
  File "C:\Users\f3d0m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection\metrics\coco_evaluation.py", line 22, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import object_detection_evaluation
  File "C:\Users\f3d0m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\object_detection_evaluation.py", line 39, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
  File "C:\Users\f3d0m\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 21, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
ImportError: cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2'`

Comment: in what folder do you run code ? Did you try to `import string_int_label_map_pb2` ?

Comment: @furas I'm running the code in C:\Users\f3d0m\models\research\object_detection and running `import string_int_label_map_pb2` gives me `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'string_int_label_map_pb2'`. I've updated the question to contain the full error code. Thanks!

Comment: if you run in folder `object_detection` then maybe it should be `from protos import string_int_label_map_pb2`

Comment: @furas Thank you so much!!!! I manually edited all the .py files from `from object_detection.protos` to `from protos` and now it's working!